# Select keys of all subobjects with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have an input object with nested objects like this:

```json
{
  "qux": {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2,
    "baz": 3
  },
  "zyx": {
    "foo": 4,
    "bar": 5,
    "baz": 6
  }
}
```

I'd like to restrict the sub-objects by the same set of keys, say `foo` and `bar`:

```json
{
  "qux": {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
  },
  "zyx": {
    "foo": 4,
    "bar": 5
  }
}
```

I can do this with `map_values`, but it's such a basic thing I want to do that I feel like I must be missing something:

```sh
$ jq 'map_values({foo, bar})' <<EOF
{
  "qux": {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2,
    "baz": 3
  },
  "zyx": {
    "foo": 4,
    "bar": 5,
    "baz": 6
  }
}
EOF
{
  "qux": {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
  },
  "zyx": {
    "foo": 4,
    "bar": 5
  }
}
```

Is this the simplest and most readable way of selecting a set of keys from all sub-objects?

I was kind of thinking there would be a `.*.{foo, bar}` type thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution using `map_values({foo, bar})` is certainly a good candidate for being minimal, but it depends on your exact requirements.  For example, if you wanted to impose the requirement recursively, you could consider:

```
walk(if type=="object" and .foo then {foo,bar} else . end)
```

At least you get some mileage here by avoiding `map_values`.

Comment: I really wanted to know if that was the right approach, and from what you've said it sounds like it's at least a reasonable one. So that's good!

Comment: So there in fact _is_ no `.{everything}.{foo, bar}` type selector. That's a shame!

Comment: That's right, `{everything}` is short for `{"everything": .everything}` :-)

Comment: I really meant, there's no way to select everything at a given level. Like `.*.{foo, bar}`.

Comment: No way?  Maybe you mean "no other way", since (as you know), that's exactly what `map_values({foo,bar})` does.

Comment: Yes! Point taken. Thanks for all your input on this.